# SQL Server 2016 installation error

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to install `SQL Server 2016`. I keep getting the following error:

> The specified directory, `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\"`, for the `INSTALLSHAREDWOWDIR` parameter is not valid
>   because this directory is compressed or is in a compressed directory.
>   Specify a directory that is not compressed.

I have read posts online that suggest going to the program folder and uncompressing it. I have done this and it doesn't seem to work. I would really appreciate pointers on this.

Comment: This kind of question is better suited to Server Fault. However, this kind of error is often caused by Windows misinterpreting the *real* cause of another error: e.g. the parent directory might not exist or the program may require different privileges, or you might need to remove the final \\ from the path name. Failing all else, inspect the installation process using PROCMON and verify with your own eyes *what*  exactly failed, and *why*. Don't assume that the error message correctly diagnosed the true problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Error message say :

> this directory is compressed **or** is in a compressed directory. Specify a directory that is not compressed.

**or in a compressed directory**

There is one of this folders is compressed or both.

So follow this steps :

- Check if `YourDrive` is **compressed** if it is then **Uncompressing** it.
- Check if `Program Files (x86)` folder is **compressed** if it is then **Uncompressing** it.
- Check if `Microsoft SQL
  Server` folder is **compressed** if it is then **Uncompressing** it.
- Try to install `Microsoft SQL Server 2016`.
- If you got the same error then try to change the `directory installation` to any `directory` which is not **compressed** .

Comment: My drive was compressed. So that was the issue. Thanks!

Comment: How to set a folder to uncompressed?

Answer (score 3):

Error message says it all,you can't install SQL server in a directory which is compressed..

Try uncompressing it first or change the directory installation to any directory which is not compressed..

Uncheck below option and try installing..

[image]

Here is a [KB which may help you](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/231347)