# C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server for INSTALLSHAREDDIR parameter is not valid because the directory is not writable

Tags: sql-server, installation

During the installation of `MS SQL Server 2014` on a Win 7 Pro computer I get the following error:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server  for INSTALLSHAREDDIR parameter is not valid because the directory is not writable...
```

There is not such a directory in the C:\Program Files\ folder! And the share directory is set to be in `c:\Program Files (x86)` folder anyhow, and I cannot even change it? I tried to create a directory `Microsoft SQL Server` in the `C:\Program Files` folder and set all the privileges, it still does not work! How come a MS product cannot be written into MS program folder?

[image]

Comment: https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2015/02/16/sql-server-installation-error-installshareddir-parameter-is-not-valid-because-this-directory-is-compressed-or-is-in-a-compressed-directory/

Comment: How come MS product cannot be written into MS program folder? Because permissions are related to your user and the folder/file settings and have nothing to do with the company that created the program, even if it was the same company that designed the operating system. If that was the case, wouldn't you be upset that MS had a backdoor into your system for everything?

Comment: Please check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38949923/sql-server-2016-installation-error . Check if your HDD is compressed!